# How can I set the selected index of an unbound DataGridViewComboBoxCell at run time?

Tags: winforms

I have an unbound DataGridView that has a column that uses DataGridViewComboBoxCells.  For some reason I don't understand, I can get the index number I want to use but I can't get the text.  (See the question I just posted.)  So, assuming I have the index number I want, how do I set the selected index of the cell?

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something… You state that … _”I can get the index number I want to use”_ … ? .. How are you getting this index number? The grids `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` and a regular `ComboBox` are two different things. They have different properties. As such, the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` does NOT have a `SelectedIndex` property whereas a regular `ComboBox` does have a `SelectedIndex` property. So technically, I do not think you can set a `DataGridViewComboBoxCells` `Value` using an index. Is there some reason you do not simply add the `string` value you want into the cells `Value`?

Comment: Due to something I don't understand about standard ComboBoxes, I could not retrieve the text associated with a particular item.  That was the reason for the "previous question" that I mentioned.  I could get the index of that item, however.  I would love to set the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell's Value` property, but I don't have a string to use to do it.  It seems very strange to me that there is a combo-box-like cell object that doesn't have the basic combo-box feature of showing the text for an item given that item's index.

Comment: I am curious about your comment… _”I could not retrieve the text associated with a particular item. That was the reason for the "previous question" that I mentioned.”_ … I can only assume you missed @Jimi ‘s comment. He shows two ways to get the “text” value of the selected item, also you could use `cboStyle.Text.` So I am not following what you mean by you cannot get the “text” value from a “regular” `ComboBox.`

Comment: In addition, I am sympathetic to your desire to have a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` act like a regular `ComboBox.` I am guessing there may be a third-party grid out there that may do this. However, can you please make it clear what “you” want to do. Are you wanting to work with a regular `ComboBox` or a grids column of `DataGridViewComboBoxCells`?

Comment: Having a discussion about “why” one works differently than the other may be considered off-topic in SO. I am just saying that the two controls ARE different and we will be glad to help you get one or the other working… we just need to know which one you want to use. Can you clarify what you are wanting to do and the problem(s) you have as opposed to comparing the differences between the two “different” controls.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments.  For now, let's forget about the standard ComboBox and just talk about a grid cell, and let's begin with the simplest question:  Is there a way to set the selected index of a DataGridViewComboBoxCell?  If the options in the cell are "zero", "one", and "two", can I use the number 1 to get the cell to display "one"?

Comment: No, you can not set the `SelectedIndex` of a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` because it does not have a `SelectedIndex` property. But you can set the combo box cells value to “one” like… `dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[“ComboCol”].Value = “one”;`